# pam_exec cannot call systemctl due to SELinux

Tags: pam, selinux, systemctl

I'm trying to execute a script every time an SSH session starts and ends, on CentOS 7. This script should start/stop a systemd service.

This is my setup:

---

In `/etc/pam.d/sshd`, I added the following line between `pam_selinux.so close` and `pam_selinux.so open`:

```
session    optional     pam_exec.so seteuid log=/tmp/pam_sshd_session.log /etc/pam_session.sh
```

I added the script `/etc/pam_session.sh`; most content is irrelevant, for brevity assume:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
systemctl stop some-service.service
```

---

This setup cannot execute my service, I see this in `/tmp/pam_sshd_session.log`:

```
Failed to stop some-service.service: Access denied
```

In `/var/log/audit/audit.log` I see this line:

```
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1701099322.109:12223): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='avc:  denied  { status } for auid=1001 uid=0 gid=0 path="/etc/systemd/system/some-service" cmdline="systemctl stop some-service.service" scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:systemd_unit_file_t:s0 tclass=service  exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" sauid=0 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
```

I found [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/854768/pam-exec-permission-denied-due-to-selinux) which describes a similar problem with calling the script itself. The script is called in my case though, I couldn't apply the proposed solution from that question to my problem since `sshd_t` (which is from my scontext) is apparently not a valid argument for the `/usr/sbin/semanage` command shown there.

What do I need to do to make `pam_exec` able to call `systemctl`?

#### Edit

Permissions on `/etc/pam_session.sh` are:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:sshd_exec_t:s0 /etc/pam_session.sh
```

I did set `sshd_exec_t` earlier while trying out things but for all I know this isn't necessary as long as I execute the file between `pam_selinux.so close` and `pam_selinux.so open`.

Comment: Take a look at `audit2allow`; that might be able to generate a custom SELinux policy to allow this to run.

Comment: Can you please provide the result of `ls -lZ /etc/pam_session.sh`?

Comment: @setenforce1 Edited question to add this.

Answer (score 1):

`audit2allow` helped me create this file `sshd_selinux_config.te`:

```
module sshd_selinux_config 1.0;

require {
    type systemd_unit_file_t;
    type sshd_t;
    class service { start status stop };
}

#============= sshd_t ==============
allow sshd_t systemd_unit_file_t:service { start status stop };
```

Along with its compiled version `sshd_selinux_config.pp`. I then enabled it via `semodule -i sshd_selinux_config.pp` and that fixed the problem.